# Open current directory in TotalCommander from CMDER (creating alias)

Tags: bash, alias, total-commander, cmder

I want to create an alias for the CMDER command line which would open my TotalCommander in the current directory. This would be the equivalent for `explorer .` command.

My alias now looks like this:

```
open. = "C:\...\Totalcmd.exe /O /R=".
```

But it just opens TotalCommander int he default directory.

Maybe someone uses such alias and knows how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got this working.

Try setting your alias as follows:

```
tc.=d:\...\TOTALCMD64.EXE /O /R="%CD%"
```

Be careful though, you have to insert it manually into the aliases file. If you do this from command line it will evaluate %CD% (current directory) at the moment of setting the alias.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It seems like the current directory is never passed to it. The tcmd window is focused but it only goes to a path if I manually add it. Which is weird cause it works with the explorer command and with a dot (`.`). It also doesn't work with other dos commands. For example if I try an `e=echo %cd%` it will print out `%cd%` or `e=echo .` will just echo `.` and not the current directory. Not sure why this is.

Comment: Are you sure you've entered it directly into aliases file? It makes a difference with these environment variables.

Comment: Seems like a different problem if even echo does not work for you. Does it work if you just execute the command (`echo %cd%`) from cmder directly?